# Reading a named pipe while multiple processes are writing to it

Tags: c, multiprocessing, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

What kind of a way is correct for solving this problem?

For example I have a program named `write.c` that has 4 child processes and the child processes are write their PIDs to a single global named pipe.

Another program named `read.c`should read this PIDs.

I have an approach like in below, but that approach has some problems.It can not read all PIDs, sometimes 3 of them and sometimes 2 of them.I think there is a synchronization problem , how can I solve this problem? :

`writer.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(){ 
    int fd; 
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo"; //FIFO file
    char buffer[50]; 

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); //creating the FIFO

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ //creating 4 child process
        if(fork() == 0) { 
            fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); //each child process opens the FIFO for writing their own PID.

            sprintf(buffer, "%d", getpid()); //each child process gets pid and assign it to buffer
            printf("write:%s\n", buffer);  // each child process prints to see the buffer clearly

            write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1); //each child process writes the buffer to the FIFO
            close(fd);

            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) { //waiting the termination of all 4 child processes.
        wait(NULL); 
    }
    //parent area
}
```

`reader.c`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

    int fd1; 

    // FIFO file path 
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo"; 

    // Creating the named file(FIFO) 
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); 

    char str1[80]; //str2[80]; 
    while (1) 
    { 
        // First open in read only and read 
        fd1 = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY); 
        read(fd1, str1, 80); 

        // Print the read string and close 
        printf("read: %s\n", str1); 
        close(fd1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't mkfifo get EEXIST after the first one?

Comment: It should, @stark, but that's an ignorable error.  It's more problematic that none of the *other* possible errors from that function or any of the others are tested.

Comment: Yes.  Need to check for errors on mkfifo and open, at least.

Answer (score 3):

This line writes the null byte into the fifo:

```
write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
```

as a result if you have two pids in the pipe you'll read the following string:

```
1234\02345\0
```

And the `printf` will print only till the first `\0`:

```
1234
```

To fix it, it's easier to transfer the PID as binary rather than formatting and parsing text:

## Writer:

```
    if(fork() == 0) { 
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        pid_t pid = getpid();
        write(fd, &pid, sizeof(pid));
        close(fd);
        exit(0); 
    }
```

## The reader:

```
fd1 = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY); 
pid_t pid;
while (1) // whatever is your termination condition
{ 
    read(fd1, &pid, sizeof(pid)); 
    printf("read: %d\n", pid); 
} 
close(fd1);
```

Comment: Maybe change it to '\n' so there is still a separator.

Comment: Or just leave it `'\0'`, which is a perfectly fine separator.  `read()` reports how many bytes it has transferred, so one can know whether to try to look past the null byte.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: true but that would require extra parsing.

Comment: Lest it be overlooked, one of the key points here is that a FIFO (or pipe) provides an unstructured stream of bytes.  There are no message boundaries, so there is not necessarily a 1:1 correspondence between writes to a pipe and reads from it.

Comment: Not really, @ybungalobill.  `printf()` returns the number of characters printed, so the OP gets the number of bytes prior to each null from the same function calls they are already making.

Comment: Why would you want a separator? If you are writing binary data, the separator is pointless.

Comment: @ybungalobill when I tried your approach, in reader side `printf("read: %d\n", pid)` statement runs in an infinite loop. And print same PID to stdout in an infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnBollinger when I tried the above approach, in reader side `printf("read: %d\n", pid)` statement runs in an infinite loop. And print same PID to stdout in an infinite loop. What should I do?

Comment: @EasterGamer, you must check the return value of `read()` and handle it appropriately.  It tells you how many bytes were actually read and whether there was an I/O error, and in particular, it will return 0 at end-of-file (when there are no more writers and no data available to read).